# Updating ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA506II with big fast RAM

Tags: memory, asus-laptop, sodimm

Reposting from https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14496/updating-asus-tuf-gaming-a15-fa506ii-with-big-fast-ram, which is `Beta`:

I have ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA506II and use it for programming in C++, my current RAM (2x8GB) is totally insufficient when building larger projects so I wanted to buy 2x16GB.

The best RAM I found was SO-DIMM 2x16GB 3200MHz 16CL Ballistix from Crucial, then I realized using their scan that I can even go 2x32GB, but then I read many sources about it and it's totally unclear whether it's possible to run the 2x32GB version on 3200MHz or only below 3GHz (it was different on every source I saw). It's not even clear if the 2x16GB can run on 3200MHz.

There was quite often a point that only some `JEDEC` RAMs can run on their maximum frequency and I need to enable some `XMP` for those Ballistix'. I checked the BIOS and the option is not there, but maybe it's just hidden when the relevant RAM not plugged.

So basically, can you tell me the best, reasonably priced RAM that I can upgrade my laptop to? I saw so many misleading sources that I don't know which to trust. Just tell me the exact specifications if possible and I buy it.
Priorities: 1) size, 2x32 or 2x16 if 2x32 not possible, 2) frequency, 3) CL.
Will that Ballistix work correctly on 3200MHz?

UPDATE:

1. Calling `wmic memphysical get maxcapacity` returns:

```
MaxCapacity
33554432
```

, so I guess the I can't go 2x32, right?

2. There's a review on https://malta.desertcart.com/products/198041271-crucial-ballistix-bl-2-k-16-g-32-c-16-s-4-b-3200-m-hz-ddr-4-dram-laptop-gaming-memory-kit-32-gb-16-gb-x-2-cl-16 with title `DO NOT BUY FOR ASUS TUF A15`, if I assume it's truth, what are the possible differences between `BL2K16G32C16S4B` and `CT2K8G4SFS832A` making the latter working on higher frequency?

UPDATE2 to make it clearer, those are the options on relevant sites:

```
CompuRAM 2x32 https://www.compuram.biz/memory/asus/notebook/tuf-gaming/series/a15/    3200MHz CL??
Crucial  2x32 https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/asus-tuf-gaming-a15 2666MHz CL19
Asus     2x16 https://en.accessoires-asus.com/laptop/memory/modele/fa506ii            3200MHz CL??
```

Comment: **Only a very small minority of motherboards actually support 32GB DDR4 modules.**  You will want to verify your motherboard is one of those boards. I would be extremely shocked if your laptop actually supported 32GB modules.  The specifications on your laptop provided by [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Gaming/TUF-Gaming/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15/techspec/) should indicate if it does or doesn't support 32GB DDR4 modules.  FYI: **The specifications indicate the maximum amount of memory your laptop supports is 32 GB**

Comment: @Ramhound But in the other hand Crucial says that it's not true and I can use 2x32GB. I am almost sure about it, the thing is that it probably runs slower than 3200Mhz, that's it.

Comment: I can guarantee you Crucial didn't test 32 GB modules with that specific laptop.  They are making their recommendation based on the fact the processor supports 32 GB.  I have also witness instances where the Crucial tool was just incorrect.  I would have answered this question but the answer is in the specifications for the laptop.  At the end of the day my answer more than likely wouldn't answer the actual question you have.  [It won't be me but somebody will answer it](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14496/updating-asus-tuf-gaming-a15-fa506ii-with-big-fast-ram)

Comment: You have an AMD processor.  XMP is something Intel developed.  It's not supported on every AMD motherboard nor does it need to be supported.  AMD has an equivalent feature (AMP).  Your laptop more than likely has very few supported memory profiles.  Whatever frequencies are being offered with your current memory is probably all it can support.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought something like that first, but going through various forums and threads over the internet it seems that people actually use 2x32GB for this laptop. But I saw things like the BIOS update disabled the XMP (but maybe it was the Intel model, because the people usually started to mix the 2 companies together).

Comment: It does not appear ASUS sells that specific model with an Intel processor.  [ASUS has not indicated they increased the memory limits on any of their firmware updates on that device.](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Gaming/TUF-Gaming/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15/HelpDesk_Download/)  The documentation on AMD processors are horrible, so even if I wanted to parse the documentation, I wouldn't be able to since it doesn't contain the information I would actually need to answer your question.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I expected there will be someone who confirms how it works and what is the best RAM specification I can put in.

Comment: We won’t be able to make a hardware recommendation.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question with direct links to the relevant information.

Comment: This still appears to be a question seeking a hardware shopping recommendation.  There is a dedicated SE website for these types of questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I asked my friend who buys HW for some company, after some research he found this thread which explains it, reddit FTW: https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDLaptops/comments/j29rpt/what_ram_will_work_in_your_new_ryzen_4000_laptop/

So post above is correct and this was the best RAM I can use, 2x32GB @3200Mhz and CL22: https://www.crucial.com/memory/ddr4/ct2k32g4sfd832a

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before this may get closed as 'opinion-based' ;)

As the minutiae of RAM speed is going to make whole milliseconds difference in a massive operation, I'd go for whatever it takes to get 64GB in there, based on the inference that your process is going to take up 'all' RAM to operate at peak efficiency.

BTW, we don't do 'shopping recommendations', so 'Which exact RAM supplier/model?' is off-topic. The rest is on-topic.

Comment: Thanks, I remove the vendor part completely. But it seems that every model of RAM from all vendors is different, so I mean that if someone tells me the exact specifications, there will be probably only 1 model of RAM from 1 exact vendor to buy. I mean Kingston makes totally different specifications than Crucial etc.

Comment: It doesn’t matter DDR4 is DDR4.  Your machine only supports 16 GB 3200 MHz SODIMM modules.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have put since one month two kingston fury 32 GB sodimm 3200 MHz CL 20
it work perfectly at 3200 MHz on my ASUS TUF Gaming A15 . The memory controler in in the ryzen 4900H, and is designed for 64GB, so no problem and the scoring on passmark is significantly better (3204). No problem on battery mode, no freeze no blue screen, i think that the max 32 GB of asus is a marketing answer not a technical one.